# Prove that the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^1 \frac{x^{p}-1}{\log x} \, dx$ exists for $p>-1$.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that the integral 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{p}-1}{\log x} \, dx$$
exists for every $p>-1$, in a Lebesgue sense.

For $p>0$ it's just a Riemann integral. But how can I approach for $-1<p\leq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch: The trouble spots are at $0$ and $1.$ Now near $0$ we can estimate our integrand with nonchalance: For $0<x<1/e,$

$$\left |\frac{x^p-1}{\log x}\right | \le x^p+1.$$

Since $x^p$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$ (this is where $p>-1$ comes in), we're fine and convergent near $0.$

Near $1$ we need  to realize that $|1/\log x| \approx 1/|x-1|.$ That may look problematic, but it's not. Our integrand in absolute value is on the order of

$$\left |\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}\right | $$

That expression is bounded near $1.$ Why? Because inside the absolute values we have the difference quotient for the derivative of $x^p$ at $1.$ There's no problem at all with that, no matter what $p$ is (we don't need $p>-1$ for this part).

Comment: Oh, thar's good. I had trouble dominating the function around 0.